# C#: Check if a parameter of method is string? or string

Tags: c#, nullable-reference-types

I want to check if all parameters of a method are nullable or not.
For example :

```
public async Task<IActionResult> HierarchyOfRanking(sometype? orderByType)
{
}
```

For int? it can be checked by

```
paras.All(p => Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(p.ParameterType) != null)
```

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/nullable-value-types#how-to-identify-a-nullable-value-type)

But when it comes to string?, it does not work. I tracked it and found that the ParameterType of string? is not "string?" but "string". It seems like for all reference types (string, user, ... all classes), the ? works as some kind of comment rather than gramma symbols.

For example, if a is int, b is int?, a = b causes an error.
While if a is string, b is string?, a = b causes only a warning. And string? is not considered as a nullable type. typeof(string?) causes an exception.

(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/types#8311-nullable-value-types)

So the question is: Is there any way to check where the orderByType of the following method is nullable or not? Thanks.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> HierarchyOfRanking(string? orderByType)
{
}
```

Comment: Nullable reference types are a compile-time feature. It is not the same as nullable value types.

Comment: So there is no way to do it?

Comment: No, because a string is just a string. When you write String? it is just an indication to the compiler to enforce some rules.

Comment: there is no way to do it as nullable reference type is only at compile time. At the lowering stage of compilation they `?` are dropped. Basically the runtime sees no difference between `string?` and `string`. This feature is only for compile-time static analysis

Comment: @theemee while it's true that it's compile time feature - this information still must be present after compilation, somewhere, it cannot be dropped. Because otherwise, if you reference third party library in compiled form (say nuget package) - how would your compiler know which members are nullable there?

Comment: What's the purpose of the check? Do you want to know literally "is this type `Nullable<T>`? Or do you want to know if it is possible for the parameter value to be `null`.

Comment: @DStanley the latter. I'm checking if a link (to an action) can be accessed only by controller and action's names. If so, I can automatically generate a link for it. To do that, one of the 3 should be matched: 1. There is no paras, or 2. all paras have default values , or 3. all paras can be null.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with [NullabilityInfoContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.nullabilityinfocontext.create?view=net-7.0) class:

```
using System.Reflection;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var method = typeof(Program).GetMethod("Test", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
        var nullableParam = method.GetParameters()[0];        
        var notNullableParam = method.GetParameters()[1];
        var ctx = new NullabilityInfoContext();
        // for method parameter it doesn't matter whether you 
        // use WriteState or ReadState
        bool firstIsNullable = ctx.Create(nullableParam).WriteState == NullabilityState.Nullable;
        bool secondIsNullable = ctx.Create(notNullableParam).WriteState == NullabilityState.Nullable;
        Console.WriteLine("First is: " + (firstIsNullable ? "nullable" : "not nullable"));
        Console.WriteLine("Second is is: " + (secondIsNullable ? "nullable" : "not nullable"));
    }

    public static void Test(string? imNullable, string imNot) {
        Console.WriteLine(imNullable);
    }
}
```

Outputs "First is: nullable" "Second is: not nullable".
Note that there if you inspect third party library this way - private and internal members might not have this metadata available (depending on how library was compiled).

More info on how this metadata is stored in compiled binary: [here](https://blog.maartenballiauw.be/post/2022/04/19/internals-of-csharp-nullable-reference-types-migrating-to-nullable-reference-types-part-2.html)

Comment: I'm just back. Need to check it out before voting it :) Thanks